# How to convert an integer to an array of its digits in C?

Tags: c, arrays

How can I convert an integer to an array of its digits in C?
for example:
I have an integer:`int a=12345;`
I want an array which contains its digits:

```
int arrayofdigits={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: and what did you try till time?

Comment: `char buf[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", a);`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Surely 33 characters are not necessary to represent a 32-bit signed integer, even with a trailing null character?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688413/how-to-extract-digits-from-a-number-in-c-begining-from-the-most-significant-dig/26688805#26688805) out!

Comment: @PascalCuoq I don't know whether `int` is 32-bit long on OP's implementation. This buffer size ensures that the integer can be format-printed in *any* possible base along with the terminating `NUL`. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @CoolGuy, I _did_ go and check that out. You may want to read my comments on its limitations. I won't downvote it, instead I'll give you a chance to fix its flaws.

Answer (score 3):

How about we provide the idea, and you write the code? Sounds good?

1. Take the integer.
2. use modulo [`%`] operator to take out the last digit. Store in an array.
3. divide by 10 to right-shift the original number by 1 digit.
4. iterate 2 & 3 untill the result of 3 becomes 0.

Finally, once you're done, if you've stored straightaway, you need to reverse the array contents to get the digits in the same order as they were present in the number.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `x % 10` to get the units (rightmost) digit of `x`. Each of those digits can be placed into an array.
2. You can use `x = x / 10` to divide `x` by ten, effectively shifting all digits right.
3. You can detect if you've run out of digits when `x` has been shifted to the point where it's equal to zero.
4. You can. if you need them in the right order, swap them by moving in from the edges until you cross at the middle.

So the pseudo-code for such a beast would be:

```
def digits[10]
def x = 12345

def pos = 0
while x != 0:
    digits[pos] = x % 10
    pos = pos + 1
    x = x / 10

def left = 0
def right = pos - 1
while left < right:
    temp = digits[left]
    digits[left] = digits[right]
    digits[right] = temp
    left = left + 1
    right = right - 1

# Now digits[0..(right-1)] holds the digits.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below program. 
The simplest one I can think was this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a=12345;
    char c[10] = {0}; /*c is array if characters to hold the digits*/

    sprintf(c, "%d", a);
    printf("Int : %d, array of digits: %s\n", a, c);

    /*To print each digit one by one*/
    a = 0;
    while (c[a] != '\0')
        printf("%c\n",c[a++]);

    return 0;
}
```