# Is there any way to assign avalue to a variable such that the value assigned is the first two-digit of another variable?

Tags: c

I am currently doing a project from my university and I came up with logic, that if possible, can help me make my project much faster. 
Here is what I want to do, 
Suppose

```
int a=2302; //user input(Now is there any way to do the following?)
int b=23 //First two-digit of a
int c=02; //Last two-digit of a
```

Comment: The `int` value of `c` cannot be `02`: it is `2`. Note that in the general case, a leading `0` on an `int` means that the remaining digits are interpreted in octal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract digits from a number in C? Begining from the most significant digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688413/how-to-extract-digits-from-a-number-in-c-begining-from-the-most-significant-dig)

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = a / 100;
int c = a - b * 100;
```

Comment: `int b = a / 100`... not really the first two digits if the number is greater than 9999 for example.

Comment: I personally would rather go with the simpler `c = c % 100`; there are platforms offering a common div+mod operation, and on platforms where you're code is faster, I'd assume the compiler to select it by itself while optimising...

Comment: Well, yeah it will, except it's only one digit for numbers under 1000. For negative numbers is basically the same.

Comment: The 'best' solution is a very subjective choice. My answer works for a whole load of different numbers I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `value` is an `int` of at least 10, then:

```
char fdigs[3], ldigs[3];
int first2 = value / (int)(pow(10.0, (int)(log10(value) + 1.0e-9 - 1.0)) + 0.5);
int last2 = value % 100;
sprintf(fdigs, "%02d", first2);
sprintf(ldigs, "%02d", last2);
```

Will give the digits in the two wee strings (including leading zeros, if required)!

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    int first2, last2;
    char fdigs[3], ldigs[3];
    printf("\nEnter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    while (value >= 10) {
        first2 = value / (int)(pow(10.0, (int)(log10(value) + 1.0e-9 - 1.0)) + 0.5);
        last2 = value % 100;
        sprintf(fdigs, "%02d", first2);
        sprintf(ldigs, "%02d", last2);
        printf("First Two: %s; Last Two: %s", fdigs, ldigs);
        printf("\n\nEnter another number: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really, it can lose precision for floating point math and can give off-by-one results. It also simply dies with non-positive numbers.

Comment: The only way to do this right is with a good old while/for cycle.

Comment: Hmm well of course going over INT_MAX is bad. I'm not talking about that though. The result can be off by one unit even for numbers smaller than INT_MAX due to floating point arithmetic not being precise enough. I did not test this for every single number, but still.

Comment: In other words, suppose that `pow(10.0, 3)` gives something like 999.9999995 because of floating point approximation, it would be turned into 999 when casting to `int` and the result would be `value / 999` instead of `value / 1000`.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli See latest fix for rounding errors - assuming `MAX_INT < 1e10`.